# Remove duplicates without using additional buffer

Tags: java, duplicates

I wrote a simple program to remove duplicates from a String without using any additional buffers. Can someone let me know if this is a good solution? I just want to know if there is any other solution better than the below solution..

Edit: 
If I pass in 'Follow Up' as input, I should get back the unique String 'FW UP'

```
    public static void removeDuplicateString(String input) {
        String value1 = input;
        String value2 = input;
        String finalValue = "";
        int count = 0;
        char char1;
        char char2;
        for (int i = 0; i < value1.length(); i++) {
            char1 = value1.charAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < value2.length(); j++) {
                char2 = value2.charAt(j);
                if (char1 == char2) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > 1) {
                //System.out.println(i);
            } else {
                finalValue = finalValue + char1;
            }

            count = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(finalValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give us the test case? what are the parameters used and what is the expected return plz?

Comment: this seems more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

How about using a positive lookahead based regex like this to remove duplicate characters from a given String:

```
String nonDup = input.replaceAll("(.)(?=.*?\\1)", "");
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/W7EaPq

Comment: if it wants to retain the char appeared the first time and take out the same char which appeared another time, how to do it

Comment: Sorry didn't understand, can you clarify with an example?

Comment: okay, it works. if I type in "appropriate", the result is "opriate". However, if i want each char occurs only once and the result is "aproite", how to do it use the regex

Comment: `opriate` also has each character only once but at different position. Feel free to post a new question if you want a different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public String removeDuplicateChars(String inputString) {
        if (inputString.length() <= 1 ) {
            return inputString;
        }
        if(inputString.substring(1, 2).equals(inputString.substring(0, 1)) ) {
            return removeDuplicateChars(inputString.substring(1));
        } else {
            return inputString.substring(0, 1) + removeDuplicateChars(inputString.substring(1));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

public You can try this:

```
   public static void removeDuplicateString(String input) {
        char[] ch = input.toCharArray();
        char[] copy = new char[ch.length];
        char[] avoid = new char[ch.length];
        int counter = 0,count=0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < ch.length; i++)
        {
            char cch = ch[i];
            boolean duplicate = false;
            if (input.indexOf(cch)==i && input.indexOf(cch,i+1)==-1)
            {
                for (int j = 0 ; j <=count ; j++)
                {
                    if (avoid[i]==cch)
                    {
                        duplicate = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!duplicate)
                {
                    copy[counter] = cch;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                avoid[count] = cch;
                count++;
            }
        }
        String finalString = new String(copy,0,counter);
        System.out.println(finalString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works.

Another solution:

```
public static void removeDuplicateString2(String input) {
    wh:
    while(true)
    {
        for(char c : input.toCharArray())
        {
            if(input.contains("" + c + c))
            {
                input = input.replaceAll("["+ c +"]" + "["+ c +"]", "");
                continue wh;
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    System.out.println(input);
}
```

Ugly but works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "Mergesort" or a "Quicksort" (assuming you can use a temporary arry to allocate the data while you sort it, you would need an extra "O(n)" space for doing so).

Once you have the array sorted you can simply iterate through the array, comparing one element with the following, and everytime you find that a given element is equal to the same one, you shift the elements back one position.

By doing this you have :

- O(N LOG N) because of the sort
- O(N)  to iterate through all the elements
- O(M) to shift elements backwards

Depending on the number of duplicates this code can get really slow because of the cost of shifting elements backwards to erase the duplicates.